# Rate limiting a Flask API by user_id from server session

Tags: flask, flask-restful, flask-session, flask-limiter

I am trying to setup a Flask API limiter for each user. The following code limits an IP Address to 3 request per minute.

```
from flask_limiter import Limiter
from flask_limiter.util import get_remote_address

limiter = Limiter(
    key_func=get_remote_address, #limit by IP Address
    storage_uri="redis://localhost:6379",
    strategy="moving-window"
)

@api.route('/api/submit-code')
@limiter.limit('3 per minute')
def submit_code():
    user_id = session.get("user_id")

    if not user_id:
        return jsonify({"error": "Unauthorized"}), 401
```

How can I change this to limit the user instead of IP address? I am using server sessions so I'm not sure how to include `user_id` in the limiter decorator.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up modifying the decorator to the following:

```
@limiter.limit('3 per minute', key_func = lambda : session.get("user_id"))
```

The limiter will not apply to users that are not logged in. You can simply add a check in the function for this like the OP.